# Having issue with displaying JSON data from external file on to the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, javascript-objects

I have a JSON external file(`https://www...?json=1&callback=TestVideos` that contains the following data:

JSON file:

```
{
    "TestVideos": [
        {
            "msn": "",
            "title": "",
            "link": "",
            "description": "",

        },
        {
            "msn": "",
            "title": "",
            "link": "",
            "description": "",
        },
        {
            "msn": "",
            "title": "",
            "link": "",
            "description": "",
        }
    ]
}
```

Using JavaScript I am just trying to get this data to display in my console on the browser.

I have tried various implementations but I was running into the CORS error. So I thought of doing it with **JSONP** like this:

```
<html>
<body>
   <p id="output"></p>
    <script>
        function insertReply(content) {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = content;
        }
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://www...?json=1';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Even with this approach I am still not able to see the data in my dev tools on the browser. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Is there possibly a different approach to take?

Comment: `So I thought of doing it with JSONP` - JSONP only works if the server sends JSONP - if you have a CORS issue, then the **ONLY** ways to solve it are ... 1) get the server to send CORS response headers; or 2) use your server to proxy the request

Comment: `but I was running into the CORS error` please include the CORS error

Comment: @JaromandaX The content he posted *is* JSONP -- it has the function call `TestVideos(...)` around the JSON.

Comment: @Barmar - ahh, I just read "JSON file" and didn't realise he's actually already dealing with JSONP :p

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the callback function `TestVideos` to receive the JSONP.

The argument is the array, not a string, so you can't insert it directly into the DOM. For testing you can use `JSON.stringify()`, in the real application you'll want to loop over the array, formatting the data into HTML or DOM.

```js
function TestVideos(response) {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
}
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://www...?json=1';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Thanks for showing this. I do see the data on my browser but if I want to parse through the JSON to access the properties, how would I do that in this scenario? Because this JSON string is not stored in some variable so I am not sure how I would use `JSON.parse(json);`

Comment: It's in the variable `response`. You can loop over it with `response.forEach()`

Comment: You've changed the question since I wrote the answer. The original question was about JSONP, where the value is the argument to the `TestVideos()` function, and there's no need to call `JSON.parse()`.